# how do i get the checkbox value in spring controller through ajax/jquery?

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc

In JSP i have like this,

`<form:checkbox path="wdays" value="${day.getDaysId()}"/>`

And Jquery like

```
var wday = ($('input:checkbox:checked').val());
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: contexPath + "/saveShiftAllotment",
    data: "&wday="+ $('input:checkbox:checked').val(),
    success: function(data)
    {       
        alert("Submited to the Medical Department");
    }
```

and my controller like,

```
public void
saveShiftAllotment(@RequestParam(@RequestParam(value="wday") int wday)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your question, you were not clear if you just want to grab the value, no matter if its checked or not.So i assume you triggering your ajax call when the check box is checked. **`<form:checkbox path="wdays" value="${day.getDaysId()}"/>`** will generate something similar to this when rendered.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="wdays" name="wdays" value="5"/>
```

So you can grab the value of the checkbox using the id like

to grab the value.

```
$('#wdays').val()
```

to check if checked

```
$('#wdays').is(":checked")
```

You ajax call will be

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: contexPath + "/saveShiftAllotment",
    data: {wday:$('#wdays').val()},
    success: function(data)
    {       
        alert("Submited to the Medical Department");
    }
```

On your spring controller side, do the below.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/saveShiftAllotment") 
public {your_return_type} saveShiftAllotment(@RequestParam (value="wdays") int wday)
```