# how do i get the checkbox value in ajax/jquery when using spring form

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, spring, checkbox

I have a group of checkboxes deefined by path deliveryStatus as shown below

```
<form:checkbox path="deliveryStatus" value="notDelivered"/>
<form:checkbox path="deliveryStatus" value="delivered"/>
```

I read two examples which are very nice

[Example #1](http://www.overpie.com/jquery/articles/jquery-get-selected-checkboxes)

[Example #2 from StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28581118/how-do-i-get-the-checkbox-value-in-spring-controller-through-ajax-jquery)

I notice the ID comes as deliveryStatus1 and deliveryStatus2 and not deliveryStatus therefore approach mentioned in Example #1 does not work for me directly. Also when using the solution mentioned in example #2 (considering the  parent tag ID to be deliveryStatus) I do not get any result.

```
$('#deliveryStatus').is(":checked");
```

returns false and

```
$('#deliveryStatus').val();
```

gives me undefined

What is the correct way to get the selected/checked checkbox for my form(deliveryStatus) in jquery/ajax.

I noticed below code works after I realized IDs to be deliveryStatus1 and deliveryStatus2

```
var deliverystatus =  $('#deliveryStatus1').val();
alert( 'deliverystatus' );
deliverystatus = $('#deliveryStatus1').is(":checked");
alert( deliverystatus );
deliverystatus = $('#deliveryStatus2').is(":checked");
alert( deliverystatus );
```

But do not feel this is the correct way to get the checked option.
Reason being there are multiple checkboxes.

Reading the Example #1 I am considering there should be a better way to read those multiple checkboxes with same path value

---

Update to Question

Explicitly adding ID like below

```
<form:checkbox path="deliveryStatus" id="deliveryStatus" value="notDelivered"/>
<form:checkbox path="deliveryStatus" id="deliveryStatus" value="delivered"/>
```

allows me to get value by

```
$('#deliveryStatus:checked').val();
```

This is valid only if there is one selection. Therefore may not be very correct when there is multiple selection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have multiple check boxes with same path variables, they will be rendered with same names like below.

```
<form:checkbox path="deliveryStatus" value="notDelivered"/>
<form:checkbox path="deliveryStatus" value="delivered"/>
```

Will be rendered as

```
<input id="deliveryStatus1" name="deliveryStatus" type="checkbox" value="notDelivered"/>
<input id="deliveryStatus2" name="deliveryStatus" type="checkbox" value="delivered"/>
```

You can obtain the values of checkbox that were checked using the below.

```
$("input[name='deliveryStatus']:checked").each(function (){
    alert($(this).val());
});
```

If you just want to obtain the values of all checked no matter if they are checked or not, use the below.

```
$("input[name='deliveryStatus']").each(function (){
    alert($(this).val());
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for the clarification. This is interesting. I had followed you explanation in previous post as well. Thanks for helping a newb